# script opens document but not with hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm creating a script to open and run with a program that has no help files but comes with a huge PDF manual. There is no way to open it from the program, so I have set up a command to open it. The command opens the PDF when run on its own, but when I assign a hotkey, it does not work. What very basic information am I missing?

thanks,
Ellen

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
runwait C:\Program Files\FontLab\TypeTool3\TTool3.exe, , max
IfWinExist TypeTool 3
    Return
ExitApp

Return

#ifWinActive, TypeTool 3

  $wheeldown::wheelup

  $wheelup::wheeldown

  F1::
    Run, C:\Documents and Settings\Ellen\My Documents\TypeTool3WinMan.pdf
  Return

#ifWinActive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a Return before your #IfWinActive statement? If not then during startup the script will run every line until it hits the first Return, which seems to be all the way to the end for you. So also place a return after your Run, C:..... command

And oh.. Are you sure about that weird long ahk_class? It could be correct but it looks strange and if this is just a littlebit off, your hotkey would never work, so try it first with the #IfWinActive line commented out.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
;All the stuff you want to run at startup....
Return
#ifWinActive, (part of) the window name here e.g. Excel

  $wheeldown::wheelup

  $wheelup::wheeldown

  F1::
    Run, C:\Documents and Settings\Ellen\My Documents\TypeTool3WinMan.pdf
  Return
#ifWinActive
```

Comment: Yes, it's the window name. I was just about to write that, then I saw that you already had. What I found is that the name changes – the last set of digits is different – each time I open it! It's a demo version (I'm on the fence about purchasing it) so maybe that has something to do with it? Anyway, it does work without the name (I put in the returns), but then it is global. Is there a way to make it work with just the window title? I'm not sure how SetTitleMatchMode works.

Comment: Updated with SetTitleMatchMode, 2

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm now trying to have the script close with the program as in previous scripts. I tried using that CloseScript code that you gave me for other scripts in the same place, but it caused to the script to close immediately. I moved it to the end of the script (above), but that doesn't work at all. Please explain what I need to do.

Comment: if you want the script to close after you closed your TypeTool, you might try runwait, which will wait with furter execution until the just started app is closed, you just place an ExitApp after runwait.....

Comment: OK, got it (see above). Thanks again!